# Recent progresses in Maximum Likelihood for ARIMA?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, arima

I am looking for recent developments in optimization for MLE and conditional least squares especially w.r.t ARIMA.

I am using ARIMA to make some forecasts, in order to do that I have to find the best order for thousands of series which proves to be quite slow.

Thus my question of recent developments and/or implementations that I could look into to improve the current process.

Thanks.